# Moq with LINQ to entity projection

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities, moq

I am trying to integrate MOQ into my project that utilizes linq to entities - and for the most part it works as expected. The issue I am running into is when I am projecting to an anonymous object that has nullable properties that the "SQLizer" can handle but MOQ throws an exception.

For example:

```
public class Person {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual void Car Car {get; set;}
}

public class Car {
   public int Id {get;set;}
}

public class Context {
   public DbSet<Car> Cars {get;set;}
   public DbSet<Person> People {get;set;}
}

// Just to show we have a person in the db without a car
context.People.Add(new Person{
   Id = 1,
});

// This throws an exception on MOQ, but works in SQL
context.People.Select(person => new {
   personId = person.Id,
   carId = (int?)person.Car.Id
});
```

I tried to only highlight the issue I was having, maybe not the best structure of data. Thoughts on how to handle this? The easiest is checking for null values prior to the projection, but I feel like there is probably a better alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are adding a new `Person` using your context, it seems you are skipping to add the `Car` instance and trying to access it later:

```cs
context.People.Select(person => new {
   personId = person.Id,
   carId = (int?)person.Car.Id // above you instantiated a Person without a Car instance
});
```

What is happening here is that during the projection of the new element, the `Select` statement is trying to access the `Car` instance, which simply doesn't exist.

However, if you want to have `Person` instances which will not contain
`Car` change your code to match one of two approaches:

**1st option (use [null-coalescing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) and [null-conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) operator)**

```cs
context.People.Select(person => new {
   personId = person.Id,
   carId = person.Car?.Id ?? 0 // 0 is the default value in case if Person doesn't have Car
});
```

**2nd option use filtering**

```cs
context.People.Where(p => p.Car != null).Select(person => new {
   personId = person.Id,
   carId = person.Car.Id
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! I was hoping to avoid adjusting the projection code - and rather have moq adjust to allow for those null instances. I just thought I might have been missing something.